# Send raw text directly using js or browser's native script

Tags: javascript, printing, google-chrome-extension

I need to send some raw text to a specific printer, but I need to do that with JS or a browser's own script, like Chrome extensions.

The company has some stores over the city and each of them have a raw printer. As it is an internal website, we can make all stores use a specific browser, so making a google chrome extension or something like that wouldn't be a problem.

It can't be OS specific binary and it can't be java applet.

Javascript, chrome extensions, firefox extensions? 
My first thought was to use chrome extensions to list all printers to the users diretcly on the page, so the user chooses one from the select box and hit print, then the scripts generates a raw text and send it directly to the chosen printer.

UPDATE 1:
I need suggestions and know if chrome extensions or firefox plugins can do that.
It can't have CSS and HTML because the printer is a basic one that only prints raw text, so it can't have margin and stuff like that.
It needs to be cross browser and cross OS.

Comment: So you're asking for suggestions? Or confirmation that your Chrome extensions concept is a good idea? Or...? If the user still has to choose a printer isn't a more standard web page print (with print-specific CSS) good enough?

Comment: How direct does it have to be? Is there a reason you can't create a (secure-able) web service or page that sends the text it received to some printer for you?

Comment: thanks for the comments, I've edited the question, if you need more info, please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used jZebra.
Its an applet, I said it couldn't be java on the question, but with jzebra, I didn't have to touch java, it is very good and easy:

https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/